# extracting first value from a list

Tags: r

I would like to extract the first value from this list:

```
[[1]]
 [1] " \" 0.0337302" " -0.000248016" " -0.000496032" " -0.000744048"
 [5] " -0.000992063" " -0.00124008"  " -0.0014881"   " -0.00173611" 
 [9] " -0.00198413"  " -0.00223214"  " -0.00248016"  " -0.00272817" 
[13] " -0.00297619"  " -0.00322421"  " -0.00347222"  " -0.00372024" 
[17] " -0.00396825"  " -0.00421627"  " -0.00446429"  " -0.0047123"  
[21] " -0.00496032"  " -0.00520833"  " -0.00545635"  " -0.00570437"
```

the name of this test is `M`, I have tested this `M[1]` and `M[[1]]` but I don't get the correct answer.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to subset the list, and then the vector in the list:

```
M[[1]][1]
```

In other words, `M` is a list of 1 element, a character vector of length 24.

You may want to use `unlist` `M` to convert it to just a vector.

```
M <- unlist(M)
```

Then you can just use `M[1]`.

To remove the `\"` you can use `sub`:

```
sub("\"","",M[1])
[1] "  0.0337302"
```

Comment: YES, Thanks, How can I delete `\\` from it

Comment: Use `sub`, I'll put an example in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The first element in the list you've shown is the entire vector shown by

```
 [1] " \" 0.0337302" " -0.000248016" " -0.000496032" " -0.000744048"
 [5] " -0.000992063" " -0.00124008"  " -0.0014881"   " -0.00173611" 
 [9] " -0.00198413"  " -0.00223214"  " -0.00248016"  " -0.00272817" 
[13] " -0.00297619"  " -0.00322421"  " -0.00347222"  " -0.00372024" 
[17] " -0.00396825"  " -0.00421627"  " -0.00446429"  " -0.0047123"  
[21] " -0.00496032"  " -0.00520833"  " -0.00545635"  " -0.00570437"
```

you get that vector by doing `M[[1]]`

To further get the first element of this vector just recognize that M[[1]] is the vector you want the first element of so use normal subsetting to get that: `M[[1]][1]`

```
> M[[1]][1]
[1] " \" 0.0337302"
```