# Extract first url from text

Tags: r, regex

Let's say we have a sentence like this:

```
sentence="thanks for coming please visit https://www.stackoverflow.com for more or look me up on https://www.linkedin.com"

sentence=as.data.frame(sentence)
```

I'd like to extract the first url only

This method works when a sentence contains one url, but not when there are multiple

```
library(qdapRegex)

#Extract Url
sentence[["URL"]] <- unlist(rm_url(sentence[["sentence"]], extract=TRUE))
```

Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to find URLs within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038061/regular-expression-to-find-urls-within-a-string) **or** [extracting first value from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950221/extracting-first-value-from-a-list)

Comment: The `str_extract` function from the stringr package should work:  `trimws(str_extract(sentence$sentence, "http.+? "))`  Assumes the url ends with a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to index for the first element:

```
#Extract Url
sentence[["URL"]] <- unlist(rm_url(sentence[["sentence"]], extract=TRUE))[1]
```